# Parametric solution of an ordinary differential equation with derivative squared

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In a theoretical physics book I have encountered a differential equation of the form:

$$\bigg(\dfrac{dr}{dt}\bigg)^2-\dfrac{C_1}{r}=C_2$$

where $C_1$ and $C_2$ are real constants, with $C_1>0$ ($C_2$ might be negative).

The solution is stated to be the following, in parametric form:

$$\begin{cases}r(\theta)=A(1-\cos\theta) \\ t(\theta)=B(\theta-\sin\theta)\end{cases}$$

where $A$ and $B$ are constants related to the original constants $C_1$ and $C_2$.

The book just states this final result, without any explanation or intermediate calculations. How can I solve the equation to arrive to this conclusion? I am completely lost, as it is not a linear equation ($dr/dt$ appears squared) and there is also $r$ in the denominator of the second term. I suppose there is some trick that can be used in this particular case, but how to proceed?

Comment: you can take square root and integrate it directly.

Comment: @MathFail Oh, wow, of course. I feel so dumb now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Question about the fall of an object in a straight line into the sun occurs quite regularly. This is a special case, the restriction to one dimension, of the general two or three-dimensional gravity equations. The given differential equation results if you write the Hamiltonian in polar coordinates and set the angle constant.

The solution as given is the parametrization of a general orbit in 2D and standard position as parametrized by the eccentric anomaly (yes, that is a standard name, look it up in wikipedia or any physics encyclopedia)
$$
x(E) = a\cos E-ea\\
y(E) = b\sin E
$$
using polar coordinates from the center of the ellipse, shifted so that the origin is in the focal point containing the mass center. $a,b$ are the half axes, $e$ is the eccentricity.

The eccentric anomaly $E$ is connected to the mean anomaly $M$ (which is proportional to time $t$) via the Kepler equation
$$
2\pi\frac{t}{T}=M=E-e\sin E,
$$
with $T$ the period of the orbit.
Now insert $e=1$ for the case where the small half-axis $b$ is zero and you get the equations of the reference solution
$$
x(E)=-a(1-\cos E)\\
t(E)=\frac{T}{2\pi}(E-\sin E)
$$

The variable names used are usual in celestial mechanics, the discussion of the Kepler laws. In the context of the one-dimensional gravity equation from the text book, one has $r=x$, $\theta=E$, $A=-a$ and $B=\frac{T}{2\pi}$.

Comment: What are you even talking about? Did ChatGPT write this? How is this related to my question?

Comment: This is the most likely context of how your book got to the cited parametrization. The one-dimensional gravity model with $x=r$ as special case of the two-dimensional gravity model. Take the derivative of your equation and divide by $\dot r$ to get the more common $\ddot r = -\frac{C_1/2}{r^2}$.